# with useEffect API call, unable to switch to another route from the mounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, use-effect

I am calling an my API with useEffect and it works fine, but when I click on a `Link` component to another page I am getting:

```
TypeError: func.apply is not a function
```

Here is my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
import dummy from '../../dummy';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: "90%",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    marginRight: "auto",
    marginTop: "80px",
  },
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: "40px",
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  card: {
    flex: "20%",
    minWidth: "200px",
    backgroundColor: "#212121",
    marginLeft: "10px",
    marginRight: "10px",
    marginBottom: "20px",
  },
  title: {
    color: "white",
  },
  desc: {
    color: "white",
  },
});

const StackList = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [displayPosts, setDisplayPosts] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'http://192.168.1.17:8000/stacks'
      );
        setDisplayPosts(result.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  return(
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <h1 style={{color: "white"}}>Stack Viewer</h1>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {displayPosts.map(item =>
          <Slide direction="up" in={true} timeout={800}>
            <Card className={classes.card}>
              <CardContent>
                <h2 className={classes.title}>{item.name}</h2>
                <p className={classes.desc}>By {item.author}</p>
              </CardContent>
              <CardActions>
                <Button component={Link} to="stacks/test" size="small" style={{color:"white"}}>View Weapon Stack</Button>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Slide>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am clicking on `<Button component={Link} to="stacks/test" size="small" style={{color:"white"}}>View Weapon Stack</Button>`

I can load other routes just fine from my sibling navbar component.

If I change out my useEffect call with a mock JSON response, everything works just fine.

I know this must be something simple that I am missing, but I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: BTW don't pass an async function to useEffect

Comment: Can you post your imports, please?

Comment: I have added in the rest of the source

Comment: I have removed the async function and everything is working now. Thanks for the tip.